# condition check issue in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my xml

```
       <ServiceIncident xmlns="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
             <Asset>
             <Asset_Tag>900</Asset_Tag> 
             </Asset>
         <ConfigItem>
       <CINum>1024</CINum> 
         </ConfigItem>
```

The below is the condition

```
       if Asset_Tag < 1000, do not map the Asset element at all, but do map ConfigItem

       if Asset_Tag > 1000, do not map the ConfigItem at all,but do map Asset_Tag
```

For the above two conditions i have written the following xsl code

```
    <xsl:template match="r2:Asset/r2:Asset_Tag">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="r2:Asset_Tag &lt; 1000">
         <xsl:value-of select="r2:ConfigItem/r2:CINum" />           
         </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="r2:Asset/r2:Asset_Tag" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
    </xsl:copy>         
    </xsl:template>
```

Please help me on this

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You're inside a template matching the `Asset_Tag` element, but your xpath expressions are written as if the context node was the `ServiceIncident`. Try something more like this:

```
    <xsl:when test=". &lt; 1000">
     <xsl:value-of select="../../r2:ConfigItem/r2:CINum" />           
     </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:otherwise>
```

But it may make more sense to split the logic into other templates, or change the existing template to match the `ServiceIncident`, it's impossible to say without seeing more of your stylesheet.